# Apache CXF RS Extensions issue in 2.4.0

Tags: rest, cxf

I'm using Apache CXF version 2.4.0.  I'm trying to create a Restful service.

The below example works in 2.3.4 but does not work in 2.4.0.  What should I do different in beans config file?

When I include the below xml line in my bean config file.

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml" />
```

I get the following stacktrace error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Failed to
>   import bean definitions from URL
>   location
>   [classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml]
>
> Offending resource: ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>
> IOException parsing XML document from
>   class path resource
>   [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml];
>   nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class
>   path resource
>   [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml]
>   cannot be opened because it does not
>   exist     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)

My POM dependency is below.  This will work for 2.3.4 but not for 2.4.0.  Any suggestions?  Is that xml extension line deprecated or included in another jar?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's no longer needed.   With 2.4.x, most of the META-INF/cxf files are no longer needed and can be removed.   Really, the cxf.xml one is the only one needed.

Comment: It didn't work for me... I am not able to send the json like I was doing it when I had apache 2.2.3 version. Getting the response as "No message body writer has been found for response class". Suggest something

Answer (score 1):

Here is the CXF information about embedding cxf inside spring in version 2.4 and above.
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/embedding-cxf-inside-spring.html