# REST CXF and Spring cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding File not found exception?

Tags: spring, rest, cxf, java-io

**i'm trynig to develop a REST web service using CXF 2.6.0 and spring 2.5.6 my CXF maven dependancy in the pom.xml  are   :**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
   </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-search</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**I'am using Spring 2.5.6 and i have declared my web service in the applicationcontext.xml  spring file :**

```
<jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/sav">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="wssav"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
</jaxrs:server>

 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
```

**And i have declared my Web service into web.xml file by this code :**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**when i deploy my project on tomcat i got this exception for the second file of import in applicationcontext.xml file :**

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: Alternatively, you might check out TomEE Plus which is Tomcat with CXF already integrated (plus some other things). http://tomee.apache.org

Answer (score 12):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6352007/320180), this file is no longer required for cxf > 2.4.x.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the line that imports cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml.
The other 2 xml files are in the cxf-X.Y.Z.jar.
For me that is cxf-2.7.7.jar.

Answer (score 0):

The file META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml is available in the below artifact.

```
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>2.2.7</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

In applicationContext.xml, comment out the below imports works for me in cxf 3.1.10.
import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding.xml