# where to find cxf/cxf.xml, cxf-extension-soap.xml, cxf-servlet.xml

Tags: web-services, wsdl, cxf

I'm new to any of open framework(I'm a solution engineer based on java) and trying to build a cxf project.

I understand that I need to have `applicationContext.xml` file and contents something like

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client ReceiveTimeout=“300000“ AllowChunking="false"/>
</http-conf:conduit>

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging />
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>

</beans>
```

in it.

I now wonder where I can download
`cxf/cxf.xml, cxf-extension-soap.xml, cxf-servlet.xml` files.

Or that I created a Dynamic Web Project is wrong? Does some other project type automatically generates those files?

Comment: Or any guide for basic cfx environment setting? guys?

Answer (score 10):

I know this is an old post, but this might help others

`cxf-extension-soap.xml` is in `cxf-rt-binding-soap` jar, but you will need `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws`

`cxf-servlet.xml` is in `cxf-rt-transports-http` jar

`cxf.xml` is in `cxf-rt-core` jar (which is a transitive dependency of the above ones)

Therefore, if you include `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws` and `cxf-rt-transports-http` as dependencies (with Maven, for example) your project should work correctly.

Comment: For anyone (like me) still working with CXF, starting from CXF 2.4.0 you no longer need to import the cxf-extension-*.xml files ([source](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/embedding-cxf-inside-spring.html)).

Answer (score 4):

Each of these files can be found in the CXF jars that you'll need to include with your project.

[cxf-servlet.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/rt/transports/http/src/main/resources/META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml?view=markup)

[cxf.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/rt/core/src/main/resources/META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml?view=markup)

[cxf-extension-soap.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cxf/trunk/rt/bindings/soap/src/main/resources/META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml?view=markup)

I've always found the fastest way to getting a CXF project up and running is to use a Maven Archetype.

Answer (score 4):

> Or that I created a Dynamic Web Project is wrong? Does some other project type automatically generates those files?

The war file you create will generally just have a manifest file under `META-INF` directory called `MANIFEST.MF`. This file has your build meta information. For me I have

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Gradle-Version: 2.0-rc-2
Created-By: 1.6.0_31 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Version: 10.51
Build: dev
Build-Timestamp: 10/01/2015 12:53:32
Build-User: athakur
Build-Host: ATHAKUR
```

This directory is automatically created when you build your project to create a jar or a war. It can have other attributes as well like the main class [[Refer this Q]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70216/whats-the-purpose-of-meta-inf).

Now coming to your question. Many libraries put their configuration files in the corresponding jars META-INF folder. This is just another example and the jars you are looking for are CXF jars.

[image]
[image]

For gradle you can add following in your `build.gradle` file

```
compile("org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:3.1.3")
compile("org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:3.1.3")
compile("org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.3")
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post but it still comes up for people migrating old CXF to newer. And what I'm finding is that `cxf-rt-bindings-soap-3.1.7.jar` no longer has `classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml`

see this: [REST CXF and Spring cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding File not found exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721243/rest-cxf-and-spring-cxf-extension-jaxrs-binding-file-not-found-exception)

Answer (score 1):

the cxf-extension-http.xml and cxf-extension-soap.xml for the version 3.2.X of cxf you just need to include this line cxf-extension-jaxws.xml

Comment: From Review: Would you please EDIT your answer and improve formatting, and break your explanation in more lines? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Web.xml can be like this

CXF

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:ApplicationContext-cxf.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Following is a working ApplicationContext.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd">


    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-xml.xml"/>
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />

    <task:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.smoothexample">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Component" />
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.smoothexample" />


    <bean
        class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


<bean id="addressSoapService" class="com.smoothexample.cxf.soap.ws.impl.AddressSoapServiceImpl" />

    <jaxws:endpoint id="addressEndpointId"
        implementorClass="com.smoothexample.cxf.soap.ws.impl.AddressSoapServiceImpl"
        implementor="#addressSoapService" address="/addressSoapService">

    </jaxws:endpoint>

</beans>
```

All the maven dependencies are defined as follows, which includes jars for cxf/cxf.xml, cxf-extension-soap.xml, cxf-servlet.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.lal.pro</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-cxf-soap-ws</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>apache-cxf-soap-ws Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <cxf.version>2.5.0</cxf.version>

        <org.springframework.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>

        <ch.qos.logback.version>1.1.3</ch.qos.logback.version>
        <org.sl4j.version>1.7.12</org.sl4j.version>
        <spring.ws.version>2.2.4.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>apache-cxf-soap-ws</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please find more details at http://www.smoothexample.com/webservices/apache_cxf_soap_web_services.html